# process builder multiple __r fields

Tags: process-builder, childrecords

I am trying to use the process builder to update a child record.

The child object called CustomerOfTheWeek, has multiple lookups to Account (for various customers, like the 1st customer, the 2nd customer etc).

In process builder when I choose "select a record related to Account", I can see multiple entries like CustomerOfTheWeek__r, CustomerOfTheWeek1__r, CustomerOfTheWeek2__r, etc.

When I click on any of them, API name is truncated, so can't exactly say which one is the right one.

How can I lookup and see for example CustomerOfTheWeek1__r is related to which field in CustomerOfTheWeek?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized there is a field on the lookup field called:

> Child Relationship Name

Please note __r is dropped from the end, but this value is basically what shows up in process builder.